# Entity Framework POCO Object Creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

we are currently using EF 4.1 and are thinking about a new alternative for our object model which is terrible. We do have POCOs in a sort of BL-Layer and above a GUI-Model with Objects wrapping the POCOs to offer BindingLists to the UI instead of the BL's IEnumerables.

We thought about deriving the UI-Model from the POCOs but I have no Idea how this would work with the EF instantiating the objects as it shouldn't know anything about the UI objects. Is there some way to move the instantiating process to factories or does anyone have an idea how to promote the object afterwards from base to derived type (which isn't really a good idea at all, is it?)

Any help, suggestions or comments would be highly appreciated.

Best regards
Gope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to move object instantiation to factories. Because of that deriving custom classes from your entities will not work because EF will not create those instances for you and you will also not be able to persist those instances because EF will not know how to map them.

Comment: Actually I only want to store the base information. The derived type should only wrap the IEnumerables as BindingLists for the UI (WinForms). The idea would be that the EF and the whole BL only know about the object as a base type and storing that should work. I just have no idea what the best way of creating these objects would be. Maybe promoting them? But that would make problems with the references within the context, wouldn't it? Or is it just based on the technical IDs?

Comment: It will simply not work. There is no way to tell EF to create your own not mapped derived instance and it will not take it for persistence.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for this information. So do you believe it would be helpful to try something like object promotion (base to derived) as there won't be any additional persisted data in the derived class or would you just skip the idea and stick with the current mapping solution?

Answer (score 0):

The introduction of POCO support in EF4 was to allow the business objects to exist without extending objects in the EF (specifically EntityObject). I've worked on a number of systems now where the domain model is shared across all layers in the system and a repository patterns is used to handle object persistence. A number of teams use the concept of data transfer objects (DTO) to provide the UI with a lightweight object that the UI can work with (which also provides a certain degree of abstraction to the BLL from the UI).

Microsoft Spain recently published a document and sample application that talks about how to structure enterprise applications (http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/) which might give you some ideas about how to structure things better.

Comment: Actually what MS Spain produced is the crap. The only thing you can do with it is avoid it or perhaps even don't read it because it is full of wrong concepts and anti patterns. Here you can check some [review](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/reviews).

Comment: Hello Dave,
I am currently following Ayende concering the MS Spain App, although I think he's exaggerating a little. :)
We are far from a good design and this is the only chance of merging the two existing (wrapping the POCOS) models into one, if only this can be done with ef.
I do need BindingLists within the UI. Mapping from the domainmodel objects is what we are currently doing and it's just terrible because of the high cohesion between the single objects. I believe deriving the UI-Model classes could help here... Thank you though for your time.

Comment: @ladislav - having read through Ayende's posts, I can't say that I agree with him. His first two are basically 'this looks scary'. Other posts take things out of context and then make incorrect assumptions (e.g. SRO for WCF facade interface). I don't think the MS code is (anywhere near) perfect but it's meant as a demo for how patterns in a DDD example work. Funny that Ayende's now writing his own DDD guide now - that wouldn't imply a conflict interests in his posts on the matter at all... ;)